# Python3 Splitting source code in multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I know this has been answered in other topics but I need an answer on a specific case :

Assume the simple case described below:

1. main.py file with contents :

```
import math     # standard math module/lib
import file1    # my file/module 

var1=math.factorial(10) # i.e. the main.py uses the math module
print(var1)

myFunc_1() # and also calls/uses the myFunc_1() from file1.py
```

2. file1.py file with contents :

```
import math
def myFunc_1(): # this is a func that also uses a math method/func
    var2=math.factorial(5)
    print(var2)
```

So my questions for running the program using:
python3 main.py
are :

a. Do I need to have "import math" in both files, i.e. main.py and file1.py as they both use math? In the future, I may need to use file1.py for other apps too, so it's a file containing just general functions, which use math.

b. In main.py I noticed that `import file1` does not work as I need but with `from file1 import *`  it runs with no errors.
Could you please describe in simple words the difference?

Comment: What do you mean by :  but not the file itself

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-whats-the-difference-between-import-foo-and-from-foo-import.htm

Comment: More than clear. Thank you all

Comment: Based on your link and to my understanding, there should be no problem if I use "import file1" when file1 is my file containing classes,functions and variables that I have created, right? There may be a problem when I use a variable or method name that is in my main file and is also defined in file1.